# Does the radius of the base equal the height in a right circular cone?

Tags: geometry, related-rates

I am doing [question 6](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01-single-variable-calculus-fall-2006/exams/prexam2a.pdf) of a practice calculus exam, namely:

> A container in the shape of a right circular cone with vertex angle a
>   right angle is partially filled with water. a) Suppose water is added
>   at the rate of 3 cu.cm./sec. How fast is the water level rising when
>   the height h = 2cm.?

My answer was  ${dh\over dt} = {3\over 4\pi} \cdot {c^2}$, where $c$ is a fixed constant equal to the ratio of the height to the radius.

The [given solution](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01-single-variable-calculus-fall-2006/exams/prexam2asol.pdf), however, is  ${dh\over dt} = {3\over 4\pi}$. The solution uses the assumption that "$r=h$ since this is a right circular cone." Is this a reasonable assumption? I have checked definition of right circular cone and cannot find anything about this.

Thanks,

Josh

Comment: Are you sure you have quoted the question properly?

Comment: @Sam Yes, I copied it from here: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01-single-variable-calculus-fall-2006/exams/prexam2a.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me amplify Roddy's answer.

1. A right circular cone has a circular base; let's assume that it's at the origin of 3-space, and that the base lies in the $xy$-plane
2. The cone is "right" so that its vertex lies along the perpendicular to the base-plane, through the base-center. So let's go ahead and say that the vertex is at the point $(0,0,h)$, just to give the thing a coordinate. ("Right" here says nothing about "right angle" -- it means "upright rather than slonched over to one side", to use the technical term :) )
3. Looking solely at the $xz$-plane, i.e., a slice through the cone, we see a cross section that looks like this shape: $\wedge$, with the angle at the vertex (location $(0,0,h)$, remember) being a right angle (because the problem says "with vertex angle a right angle"). The location of the bottom vertex of the right leg is then $(r, 0, 0)$ (because $y = 0$ in the $xz$-plane, and because the whole bottom of the cone is in the $z = 0$ plane).
4. If we drop a vertical line from the top of the wedge to the $z = 0$ line in our picture, the half-angle at the top is 45 degrees. That makes the ratio of the legs of the triangle (which are $r$ and $h$ in length) be $\tan 45 = 1$. Hence $\frac{r}{h} = 1$, so $r = h$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response! I see now that I had combined the notion of a right circular cone and the cone having a right angled vertex. Oops!

Answer (score 2):

Really it assumes, the 90 degree angle at the vertex, is split in two by the height, which produces the $r=h$ result. It's a valid assumption, unless you want a deformed cone with more area on one side of the height than the other.

Comment: I'm happy that the right angle means the vertex lies directly over the centre of the base of the cone. But without any known specific values (or ratio) for the radius or base, I don't think we can say that they are equal.

Comment: tan(45)=1 it really is that simple.

Comment: Also the right angle only matters for the r=h argument, it's a requirement to split equally in two for all right circular cones. regardless of angle at the vertex.

Comment: @JoshTaylor: The problem states that the cone is one "with vertex angle a right angle"; as Roddy restates it, the cone has a "90 degree angle at the vertex". *This* (along with the fact that the vertex lies directly above the center of the base) is what gives the equal dimensions. .. That said, it does seem curious that the official solution emphasizes the right-cone-ness, when that seems far more likely to be understood than right-angle-vertex-ness. (Perhaps the editor accidentally conflated the two different uses of "right".)

Comment: Aha! I see it now! Thank you both for your help. I was confusing it being a right circular cone with the vertex being a right angle and conflating the two.